# how to use angular2 application as dependency

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular2 application structure is like this:

```
|
|_ app.module.ts
|_ app.route.ts
|_ index.html
|_ Auth
|     |
|     |_ login.module.ts
|     |_ login.route.ts
|     |_ login.component.ts
|     |_ login.component.html
|
|_ Layout
|     |
|     |_ mainLayout.component.ts
|     |_ mainLayout.component.html
|     |_ header.component.ts
|     |_ header.component.html
|     |_ leftBar.component.ts
|     |_ leftBar.component.html
|
|_ Shared
|     |_ shared.module.ts
|     |_ loginService.ts
|     |_ historyService.ts
```

I have some `route.ts` file that my routing is there. In addition, I have layout component that I’ve managed layouting there. Finally, I have some services, directives and externals library that I defied them in `shared.module.ts`.
My question is, how I can use this application as external library, in another application with these feature.

- I want second application has access to all `html` files from first application and can route to them
- I want to access to all first application services from second application.

I’ve already known about similar project like `ng-jhipster` https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster, but mine is little different, I want to use html’s and routing in external library. I was thinking abt something like this. 
“convert my first application to node module and import it in my second app. Whit this I can access to all the services and directives (just like `ng-jhispter` and `jhipster-sample-app-ng2`). And then import the external node module (my first application) route at the end of my second application route.ts file , by this I can override the route mapping and access to the component and html views.”

**So, what is the best approach to this kind problem?**